# VB .net ListView control not showing any data in form

Tags: vb.net, listview

**Here is my forms, listview column created manaully from the form editor:**

[image]

**And here is my backend:**

```
    Public Class LineItemProducts

    Private Sub LineItemProducts_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, lvLineItemProduct.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim lineItem = New LineItemDB()

        'Getting lineItems from db by previous method
        Dim res = lineItem.GetLineItems().ToList()

        'Sorting the list by InvoiceID - by LinQ
        res.Sort(Function(x, y) x.InvoiceID.CompareTo(y.InvoiceID))
        lvLineItemProduct = New ListView
        Dim lvitem As ListViewItem

        For Each element As LineItem In res
            lvitem = New ListViewItem
            lvitem.Text = element.InvoiceID.ToString()

            'lvitem.SubItems.Add(element.InvoiceID.ToString())
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(element.ProductCode.ToString())
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(element.UnitPrice.ToString())
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(element.Quantity.ToString())
            lvitem.SubItems.Add(element.ItemTotal.ToString())
            lvLineItemProduct.Items.Add(lvitem)

        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

In the above code, when I debug, 30 around data from db are added into the `lvLineItemProduct` but in the output form, there is no data showing!

I am sure, something very silly I missed as I am not a regular dev in VB.

Comment: In the design view in the properties window set View to Details.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was simple. After checking few line of code, I found the problem itself. it's because of, I am initializing the listView control in form load again. just removing the following line worked

```
lvLineItemProduct = New ListView
```

I kept the question and answered myself, if it comes to anyones help anyday